# Trying to localize a Underscores starter theme

Tags: translation

I finished translating the .pot file(larehev.pot) and created a .mo file(larehev_he.mo) with my translation and i can't make it to work on my theme.

in functions.php there is a setup function and i changed

```
load_theme_textdomain( 'larehev', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
```

to

```
load_theme_textdomain( 'larehev_he', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
```

Any idea whats the problem? where else i need to change? 
I'm using the underscores starter theme.

Answer (score 1):

Please note how the translation works: The Text Domain should be same in all the places of your theme.

[On this page](https://github.com/Automattic/_s/blob/master/functions.php#L31) you can see the Theme's text domain setup:

```
load_theme_textdomain( '_s', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
```

And [on this page](https://github.com/Automattic/_s/blob/master/content-none.php#L13) (and many in this theme), you can see the implementation of the Text Domain:

```
_e( 'Nothing Found', '_s' );
```

In both the cases the Text Domain is `_s`. If you change the Theme Text Domain in `functions.php` then you have to change them in all the other places in your theme. An easier way to do this is to search for a quoted keyword like `'_s'` and replace it with your desired quoted keyword `'larehev_he'` in all the files of the theme.

Note: [there's another place](https://github.com/Automattic/_s/blob/master/style.css#L10) (`style.css`) where the Text Domain is mentioned:

```
Text Domain: _s
```

Make changes there too. So then it should work. :)

Comment: i started chaching all the names and half way i checked if it working and still nothing.

my question is how i activate my translation.